# Работа с файлом txt в Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal

У меня есть файл, с данными, например такой:

```
ЧУ ЧУ Тренировка 24.05.2011 12:56:40
2
5
5
5
5
2
5
5
5
5
5
5
ЧУ ЧУ Тренировка 24.05.2011 21:41:27
2
2
5
2
2
5
2
2
2
5
2
```

Мне нужна функция, которая будет искать последний запуск программы, т.е. определять какая строка вида ЧУ ЧУ Тренировка 24.05.2011 12:56:40 старше, анализировать числа следующие далее, т.е. 2 и 5, и если цифра 2 встречается больше двух раз, то...я там придумаю что, но пока просто вывести showmessage('Ваша оценка 2');
Соответственно если все 5, или допустимо одна две 2ки, то showmessage('Ваша оценка 5');
Как это реализовать:?

Comment: а у вас кол-во оценок каждый раз одинаковое?...

Answer (score 2):

Ну всё просто.

Ищем строку ЧУ ЧУ .. Если нашли, то следующие цифры добавляем в какой то массив / коллекцию.

Если опять нашли строку ЧУ ЧУ, то это оказывается не последняя строка ( удаляем добавленные цифры из коллекции ), после чего опять добавляем эти цифры.

При прочтении файла у нас всегда будут последние данные...

зы: Код принципиально не пишу. Развивайтесь :)

Comment: Да, но ЧУ ЧУ это имя и фамилия, они могут быть разными. Может стоит просто дописать постоянное значение в начало строки типа
Тестируемый: Имя Фамилия Время Дата
А возможно искать начинаю с конца файла?

Comment: Допишите чтото типа: --Чу Чу ...

А в программе уже будете проверять if( первых_два_символа_в_строке = '--') then begin { это фамилия... } end;